# Convert a string not a csv to an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, binary

I have a difficult task to achieve which is to Binary compare 2 files (.bin) and somehow list an array of the differences of the 2 files. Like list the addresses that the offsets occur or list the offsets themselves.

For now I have manage to read the files and extract their content in a string with

`import binascii`

`file1contents = binascii.hexlify(file1.read)`

And that should give me the hex values contained in the file WHICH ARE HOWEVER stored in the `file1contents = ""` as a string. That makes it difficult to compare so I want to convert that string into an array. Then convert contents of file2 into an Array and compare the 2 for differences. That should be a start.

Can you please help me on converting that string into an array??

I have tried storing them in `file1contents = []` but then I can't `print(file1contents)` to see what is contained.

Comment: `binascii.hexlify(file1.read)` is wrong, I assume you mean `binascii.hexlify(file1.read())`. `file1contents = []` assigns an empty list to the name `file1contents`. Why are you converting the file bytes to hex? Why not work directly with the bytes? What kind of comparison are you doing? Do you just want to find offsets where the files don't match, or do you want something more complex?

Comment: Yes you are correct. I need to convert them because the initial file is a .bin so if I just read the bytes in a string they will get converted into ascii values.

Right now I can compare those 2 strings read by binascii and count the number of differences between the 2. But what I want is to be able to also note the addresses (i.e 1AB3C) were the difference was noted. So I want ideally to end up with 1 array containing the addresses of the difference in the file1 and 1 array with the addresses in file2. I can then subtract those values to find the offset at any given time.

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me. Could you post an example of 2 small data files converted to hex, with the output arrays you'd expect from them?

Comment: `ffff
fff8
ff82
f825
825e
25ef
5eff
efff
ffff
fff8
ff82
f826
8260
260f
60ff
0fff
ffff35ff
5fff
ffff
fff7
ff72
f723
7238
238f
38ff
8fff
ffff
fff7
ff72
f724
7241
241f
41ff
1fff
ffff
fff7
ff72
f724
7244
244f
44ff
4fff
ffff
fff7
ff72
f724
7244
244f
44ff
4fff
ffff
fff8
ff80
f800
8000
000f
00ff
0fff
ffff
fff8
ff82
f825
825e
25ef
5eff
efff
ffff
fff8
ff82
f826
8260
260f
60ff
0fff
ffff`
Thats part of the result Im getting now. Its a large file as you can imagine there is no way I can post all the result here.

Comment: I can't find a decent way to post code here in the comments without it being in one line. So basically I have a counter that counts all those bytes and I can use that to determine the address that the difference is.

Comment: That doesn't help me. I don't want to see your whole files. And there's no point putting that stuff in the comments, put relevant information in your question where it belongs. Besides, it's pointless posting multiline Python code in comments since the indentation gets lost. As I said before, I just need to see two small sample files (eg 20 to 30 bytes each) that you want to compare, and the output you expect to get from those files.

Comment: Sorry for that I thought it might give you some insight. Well I can't post files here but I assume that you know how a binary file looks like, full of hex code. So it would be 20-30bytes of hex code. What I want from the output of the comparison is an Array with values in (potentially hexalified but decimal would do) pointing to-> which bytes the comparison found to be different between the 2 files its comparing. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: It's not easy to help you if you can't describe clearly what you want the program to do, and if you can't post any sample input data and desired output. But I'll post some code that you should find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The Python 3 code below creates a pair of `bytes` objects from their hex representation, and then finds the offsets where those two `bytes` strings differ.

```
# The input data in hex form, so it can be easily embedded in the script
s0 = 'ffff fff8 ff82 f825 825e 25ef 5eff efff ffff fff8 ff82 f826 8260 260f 60ff 0fff ffff 35ff 5fff fff7'
s1 = 'ffff fff1 ff82 f845 825e 25ef 500f efff 1ff1 fff8 ff82 f823 8260 260f 60ff 05f3 ffff 35ff 5ffe fff7'
print(s0)
print(s1)

# Convert the data to bytes, so it's in the same form it would 
# be in if we'd read it from files opened in binary mode
b0 = bytes.fromhex(s0)
b1 = bytes.fromhex(s1)
print(b0.hex())
print(b1.hex())

# Create a list of the offsets where the two bytes objects differ
diff = [i for i, (u,v) in enumerate(zip(b0, b1)) if u != v]
print(diff)

# Print the bytes that differ, along with their offsets, all in hex
for i in diff:
    print('{:04x}: {:02x} {:02x}'.format(i, b0[i], b1[i]))
```

**output**

```
ffff fff8 ff82 f825 825e 25ef 5eff efff ffff fff8 ff82 f826 8260 260f 60ff 0fff ffff 35ff 5fff fff7
ffff fff1 ff82 f845 825e 25ef 500f efff 1ff1 fff8 ff82 f823 8260 260f 60ff 05f3 ffff 35ff 5ffe fff7
fffffff8ff82f825825e25ef5effeffffffffff8ff82f8268260260f60ff0fffffff35ff5ffffff7
fffffff1ff82f845825e25ef500fefff1ff1fff8ff82f8238260260f60ff05f3ffff35ff5ffefff7
[3, 7, 12, 13, 16, 17, 23, 30, 31, 37]
0003: f8 f1
0007: 25 45
000c: 5e 50
000d: ff 0f
0010: ff 1f
0011: ff f1
0017: 26 23
001e: 0f 05
001f: ff f3
0025: ff fe
```